# PHP How to display mysql select query to table

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

How do you display a select query to a table? I use Dreamweaver.

Here's the query:

```
SELECT date(Date) as Monthly, sum(qtyBlackWhite) as TotalBW, sum(qtyChocnut) as TotalChocnut,
                 sum(qtyHotMama) as TotalHotMama,sum(qtyMocha) as TotalMocha,
                 sum(qtyUbeKeso) as TotalUbeKeso
FROM admin.order_queue
GROUP BY month(Date);
```

The columns in the table should be

```
 |Monthly|TotalBW|TotalChocnut|TotalHotMama|TotalMocha|TotalUbeKeso|
```

Comment: What is your PHP code?

Comment: Is google not working?

Comment: @henje none yet. don't know how.

Comment: @Strawberry can't find the one that works for me

Comment: Yeah I ment your code. Nevertheless you can look here http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php to learn about SQL connections.

Comment: @henje I just want to display the records from the database to a table in a web page.

Comment: @MarkTu To fetch data from a database and display it on a webpage you will need to establish a connection to the database and then run the query. PDO is one way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$query = "SELECT * FROM admin.order_queue";

```
    if($display = mysql_query($query2) or die("Error in Selecting : ".mysql_error()))
        echo("Success in Selecting <br/>"); //executing SELECT query


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($display))
    {
        print($row['Monthly']);
        print(" | ");
        print($row['TotalBW']);
        print(" | ");
        ...

    }   // Displaying the SELECT query
```

Try something like this